# Saving and Retrieving Score String Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, save

How would I be able to save my score string then recall it? I've seen a lot of answers for this question but they have all been on an earlier version of Cocos2d, I've tried to implement them but no luck :(

This is the code that displays the score at the moment

```
score=0;
scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:21.0f];
scorelabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
scorelabel.color = [CCColor blackColor];
scorelabel.position = ccp(0.85f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
[self addChild:scorelabel];
```

Thank you for any advice  :D

New code

```
- (id)init
{
// Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
self = [super init];
if (!self) return(nil);

int savedScore  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score_key"];

CCLabelTTF *ahighScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSUserDefaults stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score_key] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:23.0f];
ahighScore.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
ahighScore.color = [CCColor blackColor];
ahighScore.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.90f);
[self addChild:ahighScore];

return self;
}
```

Comment: save score to NSUserDefaults? You'll find answers to that when searching for this class + "save" or "score". cocos version doesn't matter for that one

Comment: use CCLabelTTF *ahighScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSUserDefaults stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",savedScore] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:23.0f];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by LearnCocos2D, save score to NSUserDefaults by

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"score_key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can retrieve the score from NSUserDefaults by

```
int savedScore  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score_key"];
```

Comment: So I added it to my code (check on the top) but im getting an error on it

Comment: use savedScore as the variable , not score_key . "score_key" is a key in the dictionary made by NSUserDefaults which stores the score of the player as an integer value.